# How to add new item in action menu bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have following `menu_main.xml` :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="Test">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_chat"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat"
    app:showAsAction="ifTest"
    ></item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_user"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="User"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
    app:showAsAction="ifTest"></item>

</menu>
```

I can see two `icon` in `App-bar` (right aligned). Now I want to add an Icon on the left most place. How can i do that?

Comment: i would recommend you use toolbar https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html and implement with a custom layout

check this tutorial:
http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html

Comment: @AdityaChauhan This is already implemented. What I am asking is to add icon just before `MaterialToolbar` text (see your tutorial)

Comment: did it help? or do you need more code?

Answer (score 1):

try it like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="..."
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="..."
        android:textColor="..."
        android:textSize="..." />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/..."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/..."
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:src="@drawable/..." />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/..."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/..." />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
....
....
..all other layout files
</RelativeLayout>
```

now in your mainactivity

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
....
```

this will be your layout file for mainactivity
1st imageview will be at start

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Actually I already have a `toolbar` and `main_menu` which is added to `toolbar` using `MainActivity`. Where do I need to add this?

Comment: That means I don't need to use Main_menu ?

Comment: you can still use main_menu in normal way as toolbar now works like actionbar, but icons that you want on left or right can be inflated like above

Comment: I think you also need to import `toolbar` layout in `mainActivity` layout.

Comment: Here is the exception:

`  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar `

Answer (score 0):

To add custom views for `ActionBar`, use `setCustomView` and provide it your own layout file or view. This will take over the space where the title of the actionbar would normally go.

Comment: That means we can't add item in action bar in left align because we can do it in right side